# Manually start screensaver with password protect

Tags: windows-7, security, screensaver

Windows 7

I wish to manually lock the computer so I placed a shortcut to scrnsave.exe on the desktop. (I do not want the user to use Ctrl+Alt+Del --> Lock This Computer for various reasons)

Problem is that when double-clicked, the screen saver starts but it's not password protected.

However, in Personalization --> Screen Saver, that same screen saver is the selected one and it IS configured to display logon screen upon resume. And that works when Windows starts the screen saver.

So how can I cause "On resume, display logon screen" behavior by manually starting a screen saver? (Scripting is an option if I know what to do.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a desktop shortcut for Lock Workstation, it's `C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation` on the target path. Then, install [MonitorES](http://code.google.com/p/monitores/) to automatically turn off the monitor the moment it's locked. Ok, it's not starting the screensaver, but it save more energy, and I think the screensaver thing was more about "click to lock"

Edit : A setting in MonitorES also allows auto starting of screensaver when locked, and it will work when you set a screensaver on Display setting. Still, I think it's better to simply turn off the monitor.

Comment: this is a better solution.

Comment: I agree. This is closer to what I was asking. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

Cannot you use the key combination of [`Window Key`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_key) + `L`?

It will lock your screen and the tasks will not be affected.

Some other useful [Keyboard Shortcuts](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/keyboard-shortcuts).

**Update:**
Well here is your screensaver solution:

As I said and you checked, the setting for `display logon screen` will only be in effect after the time set as default "`Wait`" for the screensaver passed by. Otherwise the *custom* screensaver (open by double-click) will result in back to desktop rather than logon screen.

[image]

Cheers! :)

Comment: Thanks Asif. Forgot about that one. I'll see if that is acceptable - users like to click an icon on their desktop rather than remembering a keystroke. I am still curious about the screensaver solution, though.

Comment: @gibberish see the update..hope you'll got what you wish for..:)

Comment: Hi Asif, I saw that (see para3 of my original question). Interestingly, that setting seems to be ignored if screensaver started by double-clicking shortcut the scr file.

Comment: Oops I got a pinch :) .. and Yes offcourse the default setting for logon screen will be with the _default_ screensaver popup. you can reduce the screensaver popup time if you use it more oftentimes.

Comment: I just tried that and you are right: double-clicking the shortcut opens the screensaver right away, but it doesn't become password protected until the "Wait" period specified in the screen saver dialog has expired. Please enter this as a separate answer and I'll credit you with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
powershell.exe -command "& (Get-ItemProperty ‘HKCU:Control Panel\Desktop’).{SCRNSAVE.EXE}"
```

it works but It did not lock out after the 15min timer, I left for 45min+

Our IT has locked it at 15min & must use PW, yet I can not get it to work manually.

There's got to be a script combo that does both, right? because I can force either several different ways...